# Number of spatial critical points of a solution to the heat equation in higher dimensions

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, heat-equation

I would like to know if the number of spatial critical points of a solution to the heat equation can increase. Given $u_0:\mathbb S^n\to\mathbb R$, let $u$ be the solution of the initial value problem:
$$\begin{cases}\partial_t u = \Delta u ,& \\ u(\theta,0)=u_0(\theta)&\end{cases}.$$

1. Can a degenerate critical point of $u$ at initial time develop into non-degenerate critical points at a later time?
2. Under what circumstances is the number of critical points decreasing along time?

In one dimension ($n=1$), [Angenent](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/crll.1988.390.79/html?lang=en) showed that the number of zeros of $u$ cannot increase. In particular, this implies that the number of critical points cannot increase (cf. [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/194418/heat-equation-and-evolution-of-number-of-critical-points)).

In higher dimensions ($n\geq2$), it seems that there are no references for this question. A relevant remark by Prof. Pardon in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/194315/number-of-critical-points-of-smooth-functions-on-s1) seem to suggest that for $n=2$, if $u_0$ only have non-degenerate critical points, the number of critical points of $u(\theta,t)$ is decreasing in $t$. Also, he suggested for $n=2$ that a monkey saddle can split into two critical points along the heat evolution, but I am unable to create an example.

Any references or ideas to approach the problem are appreciated.